# How to get the state of share extension in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, ios8-share-extension

I'm developing a share extension for my app.
I know that the following methods will be fired, if user minimize and reopen the app.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

I need the same thing when user minimize the share extension. The above method are not getting fired in shared extension.
I'm using `UIViewController` as super class of my share extension. Tried the following methods.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

`-viewDidDisappear` is not getting called when user minmize the app.

Is it possible to know if user minimize the shared extension?

I need your valuable suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using SLComposeServiceViewController for the share extension controller class. It is a regular view controller, would you be able to use viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear ?

Comment: Have you tried listening for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `-[NSExtensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:completionHandler:]` to return control to the host application. Use that as an opportunity to know your share extension is being dismissed.